0 or infinite limit in limit comparison test for improper integral
In this doc, the steps for using the Limit Comparison test are:

Use the LCT when trying to determine whether $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ converges and the function $f(x)$ is positive and looks complicated.
Find a function $g(x)$ which grows at a similar rate as $f(x)$ and is simpler.
Compute $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$
Make sure the limit exists and is not $0$ or $\infty$.
Note that if this limit does not exist, $0$ or $\infty$, then the LCT is inconclusive, and cannot be applied.

However multiple textbooks state the following
If $\frac{f}{g} \to 0$ and $\int_a^\infty g(x) dx$ converges, then $\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$ converges, and if $\frac{f}{g} \to \infty$ and $\int_a^\infty g(x) dx$ diverges, then $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ diverges.
Using test for limit as 0 gives incorrect answer in some cases as
For convergence of $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin{x}}{x^{p}} dx$
we have choosing $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^p}$
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{x} / x^{p}}{1 / x^{p}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \sin{x} = 0$
which gives range of convergence for p as $p<1$, however if we take $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^{"p-1}}$ we will get limit as 1 and range as $p<2$ which is the correct answer.
So in inclusion can we use the limit comparison test if limit is $0$ or $\infty$?

The theorem does not say that  $\int_a^{\infty} g(x) dx$ converges iff $\int_a^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges. In the case $g(x)=x^{-p}$, $\int_0^{\pi/2} g(x)dx< +\infty$ if $p<1$  implies that $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)dx<+\infty$ if $p<1$, which is correct

To rephrase @SineoftheTime's comment: The first half of the post describes an if-and-only-if fact, while the “multiple textbooks“ part of the post describes a one-way implication.

@GregMartin What is the use of iff here, since we have to show that $g(x)$ is either convergent or divergent to comment on $f(x)$ why would we go to the other side since we have already decided on $g(x)$

@SineoftheTime So when using $g(x) = x^{-p}$, it tell us that $g(x)$ is convergent and hence $f(x)$ is convergent, but it is giving us a weaker result i.e $p<1$ than the one we require i.e $p<2$

@dreamboat the test with $x^{-p}$ assures convergence for $p<1$, then you have to study what happens when $p\ge 1$. I would not use the expression "weaker result".
